# Removing the circle around a spiderweb chart in Highcahrts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    gridLineInterpolation : 'polygon',
    lineWidth : 0
},
```

Even though it is drawn as polygon, there is still a circle around the whole chart as if it is a radar chart. How can I remove it? Thanks
here is a fiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/mryg2vhq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working fiddle for your case:  https://jsfiddle.net/narkhedetusshar/v2jydeq1/10/

```
xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 45,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    lineWidth: 0, // you need to add this line 
    labels: {
        format: '{value}°'
    }
},
```

Comment: Ah I should have put linewidth to x-axis instead of y